# How can a reset the contents of a List or a Map?

Tags: java, object, reference

If I create an object then put that object into a List or Map, then will setting that object to null affect the content of List and Map?

like:

```
Object obj = new Object();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

list.add(obj);
map.put(1, obj);

obj = null;
```

now after this line if I want the contents in list and map both be null, is it possible?
if not, is it achievable? How?

Comment: You should be able to answer the first question by simply testing it

Comment: You need to do some operation on MAP or list for this purpose.

Comment: @kshitij it looks like you have to test this code too.

Comment: If you specifically need to reset the List and the Map (make them empty) use list.clear() and map.clear()

Answer (score 3):

> If I create an object then put that object into a List or Map, then
>   will setting that object to null affect the content of List and Map?

**No**, that will not happen. You don't put the object in the `List` or `Map`, rather a reference to that object. So, when you make yor original reference point to `null`, the references in the `List` or `Map` will still point to the same instance.

> if I want the contents in list and map both be null, is it possible?

Yes it's possible, but you would have to do it manually, by iterating over your `List` and setting each element to `null`. Same thing inside the `Map`, you would have to set each value to `null` manually.

Comment: ok. thanks. I was wondering if there was any method so that the list and map would be cleared by itself without manual manipulation

Comment: You should add that OP must *clear* the `obj` reference value from the `List` and `Map` before setting the `obj` var with `null` value.

Comment: @sabbir.. If you want to remove all the references, you have `clear()` method in both `List` and `Map`, you can use that (**list.clear()** and **map.clear()**). Then again, that would remove all the elements.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza.. And why should he do that? I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

See here `Object obj` is reference of Object type which hold reference of `new Object();`

when you do `list.add(obj);` then list `0th` index will hold the same reference of `obj` and same for map.

Now when you do `obj = null;` this means now `obj` reference will hold null not previous `Object`, **it does not effect object**.

See here your `new Object();` not yet unreachable because `list and map` still holding the reference. If there ware not into the picture then `Garbage collector` will collect the `object` because the object would be unreachable.

> `WeakHashMap<K,V>` is one example of map where.
>   An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from other Map implementations.

Comment: Umm.. Will that(WeakHashMap) work for Values? I doubt it. Because OP is setting the `Object` reference to `null`, which are values in his Map.

Comment: yes @RohitJain key is Weak there. But when your key will be removed then value also will be automatically removed as key was pointing to value.

Comment: @Quoi.. OP is removing on the basis of values actually. If he used Object as key, then only that would be possible with `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: yes you are right man. I was just drawing of weak reference's irrespective of key or value example with collection. Anyway Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> If I create an object then put that object into a List or Map, then
>   will setting that object to null affect the content of List and Map?

No. Because the `List` and the `Map` still have **strong** references to that object. So the garbage collector cannot reclaim the object from memory.

> now after this line if I want the contents in list and map both be
>   null, is it possible? if not, is it achievable? How?

As for the List and Map, you may want to use [WeakReferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to do something like this:

```
Object obj = new Object;
WeakReference<Object> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(obj);

List<WeakReference> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(weakReference);

Map<Integer, WeakReference> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, obj);

//Now set the only strong reference to null
obj = null;
```

So, if the garbage collection occurs, then when you try to do something like this:

```
map.get(1).get(); //May return null if GC ocurred
list.get(0).get(); // Same here
```

But you still have to remove the entry for the map and the element from the list.

For this cleanup, you must use a [ReferenceQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) to iterate in your `Map` and `List`.

I quote from [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references):

> An object which is only weakly reachable (the strongest references to
>   it are WeakReferences) will be discarded at the next garbage
>   collection cycle [...]

Answer (score 0):

> now after this line if I want the contents in list and map both be null, is it possible? if not, is it achievable? How?

First, don't set your `obj` to null. Loop through the list and map, compare the elements with obj and if they match, set them to null. Later set `obj` to null as well.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
  if(list.get(i) == obj) {
    list.set(i, null);
    break;
  }
}

for(Integer key: map.keySet()) {
  if(map.get(key) == obj) {
    map.put(key, null);
  }
  break;
}

obj = null;
```